# Microsoft Teams - How to retrieve information about unread messages in a Teams Channel with MS Graph

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get information about unread messages (Either just an indication, or better, a number of messages ) in a Microsoft Teams channel.

I am able to get the messages with MS Graph: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[TEAMID]/channels/[ChannelID]/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%5BTEAMID%5D/channels/%5BChannelID%5D/messages)

But how can I get unread messages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use delta query to get new or updated messages in a channel.

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/delta
```

[chatMessages: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
Unfortunately it will only give me the new messages since the last graph call.
I'm looking for unread messages, in case the user reads the messages in the MS Teams client.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have this API, you can raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have made an UserVoice [link](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/42760709-retrieve-information-about-unread-messages-in-a-te)